# Geocoder keeps returning true

Tags: java, android, geocoding

My application using a `GeoCoder` keeps returning the string to true. here is the code I have.

```
public boolean address(){
      Geocoder geoCoder = 
            new Geocoder
            (getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());

            try {
                List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(LocationManagerHelper.getLatitude()/1E6, LocationManagerHelper.getLongitude()/1E6, 1);

                String addes = "";
                if (addresses.size() > 0) 
                {
                    for (int i=0; i<addresses.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex(); 
                         i++)
                       addes += addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(i) + "\n";
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e) {                
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return true;


 }
```

and I call that into a text view.

```
add.append(""+ address()
            + '\n');
```

it works somewhat except for it doesn't show the address and instead shows `true`

can any one tell me why this is?

thanks.

Comment: So, wait: you defined an `address()` method that returns `true` - see the last line before the closing brace in the code block you posted - and you find surprising that, when you call it appending its result to a `TextView`, the text shown is `true`?

Comment: @Giulio Piancatelli, I did figure my returning statement was the problem. I need to know what to switch that to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize the result `String` variable *outside* the `try` block, then change the method's return type to `String` and indeed return the result `String` variable after having augmented it with the lines from the address.

```
public String address() {
    Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
    String result = "";
    try {
        List<Address> addresses =
            geoCoder.getFromLocation(LocationManagerHelper.getLatitude() / 1E6,
                                     LocationManagerHelper.getLongitude() / 1E6,
                                     1);
            if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                Address address = addresses.get(0);
                for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++)
                    result += address.getAddressLine(i) + "\n";
            }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

But, really, this is *basic* Java programming, so before delving into a framework such as Android I would heartily suggest you learn the language first.

Comment: Okay, so now I don't get true or -1 so that works. but I still do not get the address from the longitude and latitude. I am guessing that I need to do something other then this to get the address of a place?

Comment: That depends on what you have in `LocationManagerHelper` I believe.

Comment: Inside of the `LocationManagerHelper` all that is in there is stuff for the longitude and latitude. I was under the impression that I could get the physical address from the longitude and latitude.

Comment: I am under the same impression, too. But I haven't used location-based APIs yet, just read a bit about them, so I wouldn't be of much help I'm afraid.

Comment: Its all good. I guess I have more research to do. thanks for you help.

Answer (score 2):

You need to return the address string by using the return keyword, and changing your method return type to a String:

```
public String address(){
    Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
    String result = "";

    try {
        List<Address> addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocation(LocationManagerHelper.getLatitude()/1E6, LocationManagerHelper.getLongitude()/1E6, 1);

        if (addresses.size() > 0) 
        {
            for (int i=0; i<addresses.get(0).getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++)
               result+= addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(i) + "\n";
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {                
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;
 }
```

Comment: Well I don't get true anymore but do get -1?

Comment: Even though it wouldn't let me do `result` so I had to change that to `RESULT_OK` and instead of changing my method return type to `string` I had to have it `int` in order for it to work.

Comment: An int will return a number hence the -1. Did you try string with capital S. Also,I changed the name of your variable to result so make sure you also change the variable declaration in your code.

Comment: Just copy my code exactly. Once it works, try understanding why.

Comment: Your code won't work because `result` must be initialized outside the `try` block for the `return` statement to see it.

Comment: @GiulioPiancastelli you are quite right. Thank you for pointing that out. Fixed it.